# Selenium on shared gui-less host

Tags: linux, selenium, web-scraping

I need to run Selenium (or another webscraping tool that can handle javascript) on a remote linux host (Webfaction). I am using Python.

Is this possible? The server is gui-less so I can't run browsers. Or can I, if I use PyVirtualDisplay?

What about running Selenium with HtmlUnit?

I have tried using Selenium with Selenium/PyVirtualDisplay/ChromeDriver, but keep getting various error messages. So I'm wondering if this is even possible before I continue to debug something impossible.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to handle JavaScript Selenium/Webdriver seems to be a good solution.

If you need to run headless, [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) (instead of ChromeDriver) is an excellent alternative. It is based on [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), a headless browser based itself on Webkit. It has full JS-support.

Comment: Does GhostDriver work with Selenium or is it it's own thing? It's not on their list: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp  I tried HtmlUnit with Selenium, but that required the Selenium driver, which kept crashing, not sure why. Would ghostdriver require that you install the selenium driver and run it from a separate window - that would be bad.

Comment: It implements the Webdriver protocol (a W3C standard soon) but AFAIK it independent of the Selenium project. Its however widley used.

You may want to look at the documentation on their website, they have their own api so you can probably do without selenium in your usecase.